# Proper syntax for deploying a certificate in database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, certificate, database-project

How can I have a certificate in a Visual Studio 2010 database project that will be created, updated and removed depending on changes in the project similar to the way that it handles tables, stored procedures, keys and other objects?

Below is the syntax that I am currently using, and the `$(CertName)`.

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE [$(CertName)]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    WITH SUBJECT = N'Encrypt Data', START_DATE = N'11/26/2012 15:13:03', EXPIRY_DATE = N'11/26/2013 15:13:03'
    ACTIVE FOR BEGIN_DIALOG = ON;
```

I have tried to check if it exists using the below if statement.

```
IF (select Count(*) from sys.symmetric_keys where name like '$(CertName)') = 0
BEGIN
    --insert create statement
END
```

However using this approach I get the following errors, due to the fact that I use the certificate in the definition of the symmetric key.

> SQL03006: Symmetric Key: [$(KeyName)] has an unresolved reference to Certificate [$(CertName)].

Comment: As a workaround, you can recommend using deployment for the project and not including the certificate in the build.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.certificates where name = '$(CertName)')
```